# Automatically position more than 12 columns properly in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code that displays products on a bootstrap grid. Each product uses 4 columns of the grid, so that 3 columns per row are displayed. However, because of their varying height, they don't display properly.

**Actual result:**
[image: actual result]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #1</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #2 <br><br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #3 <br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #4 <br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #5 <br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #6 <br><br><br></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3w0hjx9/

**Expected result (simulated using more rows):**
[image: expected result]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #1</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #2 <br><br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #3 <br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #4 <br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #5 <br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Random height #6 <br><br><br></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85oewy3f/

How can I achieve the desired result without having to add a row every 3 products? (which I can't because of some features of the website)

Comment: set a minimum height of each col-md-4.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/85oewy3f/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, min-height would work, but now you're specifying a height limit on elements that just shouldn't have that restriction.

A simple solution is to leverage `:nth-child` and clears.

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Codepen: [codepen.io/hellojason/pen/QNWMOZ](http://codepen.io/hellojason/pen/QNWMOZ)

Then you can clear different `:nth-child` positions around media queries, if you need to get more granular.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the float after every third column div.

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+4) {
  clear: both;
}
```

...but really you should use Bootstrap rows at they are intended.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a3w0hjx9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the height of each `.col-md-4` as some value. The details is in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/85oewy3f/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.col-md-4{
  min-height: 200px
}
```

> May be it will be bad for project, so you can override this by adding
>   other class.

Comment: The problem with this is that I will have to set different classes depending on if the user is logged or not, the user type, etc, so I hoped there would be a better solution

Comment: that is also the issue, okey lets try different. see the other answer.